# How to sort records except first record in SQL

Tags: sql

```
Current product  TempAnn      SrNo
-----------------------------------
Current Product  0.00         1
Match            20.96        2
Match            26.96        3
Current Product  0.00         1
Match            4.76         3
Match            5.76         2
Current Product  0.00         1
Match            32.40        3
Match            35.40        2
Current Product  0.00         1
Match            20.96        2
Match            2.96         3
Current Product  0.00         1
Match            29.76        2
Match            30.68        4
Match            24.04        3
Current Product  0.00         1
Match            16.92        3
Match            13.56        4
Match            22.64        2
```

There is need of sorting Each current product where `SrNo <> 1`. For example, the first current product except SrNo 1, 2 and 3 should be sorted together so that it shows 26.96 first then 20.96.

Comment: i dint able to show it properly my records having three column current produt    tempann    srno.

Comment: Your last two sets of results do not appear to be sorted in any way that I can see.  Is what you have above your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SrNO=1 ASC, TempAnn DESC
```

Comment: Hi,I have another requirment as i want that except SrNo 1,the other records gets sorted in a way so that max value always comes in at place SrNo 2.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible, you would absolutely need another column i think:

```
Current product  TempAnn      SrNo    tempCol
---------------------------------------------
Current Product  0.00         1         1
Match            20.96        2         1
Match            26.96        3         1
Current Product  0.00         1         2
Match            4.76         3         2
Match            5.76         2         2
Current Product  0.00         1         3
Match            32.40        3         3
Match            35.40        2         3
Current Product  0.00         1         4
Match            20.96        2         4
Match            2.96         3         4
Current Product  0.00         1         5
Match            29.76        2         5
Match            30.68        4         5
Match            24.04        3         5
Current Product  0.00         1         6
Match            16.92        3         6
Match            13.56        4         6
Match            22.64        2         6
```

So you use a proper order

```
SELECT *
From table
ORDER tempCol, TempAnn
```

EDIT :

```
 SELECT *
    From table
    ORDER tempCol, SrNo = 1,  TempAnn Desc
```

Comment: Not work,i want except srno 1,the other two or three records have to sorted in descending order.

Comment: No this is another requirment.